# how do i remaining consistent across media queries when a bootstrap elements width has been modified

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am trying to shrink the width of a `well-sm` but I run in to trouble at some smaller sizes. The form will float left or right depending on the specific size.

An example of the issue can be seen  at the link below. Otherwise the page remains responsive when the width is left at 100%.

http://casouza.com/homelist

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this will solve your problem but you should know that line 147 and 148 should be reversed, according to IE.  The form close tag should be inside the div close tag for well-sm.  Also, I'm only seeing the error on IE, not on Firefox or Chrome.  It might be easier to get help if you made a jsfiddle or something - I can't replicate the error easily without all your files.  Thanks.

Comment: so I would like the well-sm to be the size it is as you see it on a desktop at full screen. as you shrink the screen down the first time it breaks is from 991px to 768 where it breaks a second time. The error is in chrome/ie/ff

Comment: You mean like this(see link below)?  You might just need to keep the div out of the bootstrapped div class container ... http://www.davidrynn.com/contact/

Comment: Yes the behavior on that contact page is exactly the behavior I am looking for.

Are you saying to remove the container classes from divs that encapsulate the well?

Comment: Yes. And the "col-12-sm".  Only tried it on Chrome but it worked better.